# How to execute sql string using SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a sql string that i would like to execute it in SQL Server 2000

Example:

```
DECLARE @CodeNameString VARCHAR(1000)
SET @CodeNameString = '%123% OR name LIKE %456% OR name LIKE %789%'
SELECT * FROM atable WHERE name LIKE @CodeNameString
```

Of course the above would be a lot easier in SQL 2008 but unfortunately i don't have that option...:

```
SET @CodeNameString = '"123" OR "456" OR "789"'
SELECT * FROM atable WHERE CONTAINS(name, @CodeNameString)
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Sql 2000 also had dynamic Sql capabilities, in which case you can execute the whole query dynamically :

```
EXEC(N'SELECT * FROM atable WHERE name LIKE ''%123%'' 
       OR name LIKE ''%456%'' OR name LIKE ''%789%''')
```

Comment: N indicates that the string following is a Unicode literal e.g. `NVARCHAR`